# how to send default values in javascript fuctions

Tags: python, node.js

Python code

```
def idea(prompt,max_token=30,temperature=0.6,n=10):
        print(prompt,max_token,temperature,n)
idea("hi there",n=300,max_token=60)

output: hi there 60 0.6 300
```

idea("hi this",n=1000,max_token = 7856)

python works fine with this and do what I expected

but nodejs

```
function callMe(a, b=2, c=4) {console.log("a:",a,"b:",b,"c:",c); return a + b + c }
callMe(a=10,c=100)

output:
a: 10 b: 100 c: 4
114
```

how to achieve same with nodejs

Comment: `callMe(a=10,c=100)` - this will not assign to the parameters `a` and `c` of function `callMe`. This will throw an error (in strict mode) if `a` and `c` are not defined in the scope that contains this function call. If you only want to pass values for `a` and `c`, call the function as: `callMe(10, undefined,100);`. Order of the function parameters should be same as the argument values for those parameters.

Comment: yeh I know that but what about if use 10 to 15 parameters in function and just want to send value for  6th and 14th parameter then in between I have to send undefined correct but this really not good as you see in python code I use the name to send parameter which is simple and clean So my question is it possible to same with nodejs   @Yousaf

Comment: _"what about if use 10 to 15 parameters in function"_ - you shouldn't be doing this in the first place; either split your function into multiple functions or pass a single object to the function. _"is it possible to same with nodejs"_ - AFAIK, you can't do this in nodejs.

Comment: Thanks But I just wish it is there and for 10 to 15 parameter thing you are write. But sometime when you call some API its need right now I am using Openai GPT3 API it has around 10 parameters so yeh I need that

Answer (score 0):

If you have that many parameters, simply pass a single object to it. Then you can set defaults:

```js
callMe(props) {
  console.log(props);

  // if you want defaults:
  const withDefaults = Object.assign({}, {
    method: 'GET' // default for method is 'GET'
  }, props);
}

callMe({}); // {}
callMe({ firstParameter: 1 }); // { firstParameter: 1 }

// with defaults:
callMe({}); // { method: 'GET' }
callMe({ other: 2 }); // { method: 'GET', other: 2 }
callMe({ method: 'POST' }); // { method: 'POST' }
```

That's a very common way to use it with many properties.

Comment: thanks I am doing same But still Python version is really cool

Comment: Ok thanks But I find my answer

```
function generateAccessToken({email,password,username}) {
  console.log(email,password);  
}

generateAccessToken(password,username,email)

```
in this way we can send parameter in any order

Comment: It's basically what I wrote, just using destructuring :)

Comment: I am new with JS so I might not understand your code but really thanks Really appreiciate  @Andrey Popov